# How to generate non existing words that are not anagram of an existing one?

Tags: algorithm, anagram

If you want to create a game based on anagrams, how would you proceed to dynamically(or not?) create a non existing words that is not an anagram of an existing word?

The **use case** is: "find the only anagram that is an anagram of an existing word"

I know that I can check for anagrams against a dictionary (like prime the prime numbers method) but.. if I have to check for anagrams for every random generated word and restart if one is found, that would take ages..
Ideas?

PS: any idea to do this adding a "similarity" parameter to the generation of the random non existing word based on the target anagram?
I'm sorry if it isn't clear, English is far from being my mother tongue, please ask if needed.

Comment: Could you give an example.  I am not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: One part is missing from the description: it seems you want to a non-anagram that seems as though it could be an anagram of an existing word and not any set of letters like "tzkl"

Comment: @AgapwIesu I'm trying to build a game wher I ask users to identify the only combination of letter that is an anagram of a real word:

Which between these is the anagram of a real world?

lihl; xyzp; hjkl;  trpx;

Obviously I could use a set of letters that is impossible for a word such as I did here, but it would be better being able to generate all sort of combinations and check if they are not anagrams for a real word.

Comment: @HansOlsson You are right. I thought I implied that saying that I'm building a game not a proof of concept on anagrams. "xylmpyz" could never be an anagram of a real word but it would make the game too simple, wouldn't it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't get it.  The examples you gave could not be anagrams, because anagrams have to be real words.  Are you saying you'd give a real word (ex: cinema) and then provide options, one of which would not be an anagram of that word (ex: iceman, came in, malice, anemic) and the player is supposed to pick out the one that is not?  Or are you just not caring about the original or the "anagrams" being real words?

Answer (score 1):

Create anagrams dictionary *(perhaps, such ready-to-use vocabularies do exist)*

For example, entry with key `aemt` (sorted char order) contains list of values `meat, team, tame`

So for given word you can sort letters to make a key and look for key presence in dictionary very fast

Comment: Thanks you, that was my idea, but looking at the dictionary size (~100.000 records at the very minimum), and having Javascript on mobile as target, I was in doubt about performances. Do you think it would be feasible with those numbers and target in mind?

Comment: I think that dictionary (hashmap or tree-based) should work fast enough for such size.